# Como proteger arquivo swf de ser executado em outros domínios?

Tags: actionscript-3, proteção

Tem como proteger um arquivo swf por Actionscript 3.0?

Eu sei que existe o `Security.allowDomain("www.example.com")`, mas ele só serve para poder receber dados do domínio que estiver entre parênteses, se não me engano. Alguém sabe algum outro jeito por as3?

Obrigado!

Comment: Não coloque em nenhum site. Deixe ele só no seu computador, Fica protegido :)

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer fazer. Proteger de quem? Do que? De onde? Como?

Comment: Não tem nenhum código no as3 que faz tipo para a swf funcionar só em 1 certo domínio ? Tipo para a pessoa quando pegar minha swf e por direto no site dela não vai funcionar só se ela decompilar e mudar o domínio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer com que o SWF fique obsoleto em outros domínios, você pode utilizar o comando `SecurityDomain.currentDomain.domainID`. Este recurso retorna um ID único do domínio de hospedagem do swf, através do objeto *singleton* [SecurityDomain](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/SecurityDomain.html#currentDomain). Assim, você pode verificar se o arquivo está no domínio pré-definido.

```
if(SecurityDomain.currentDomain.domainID == "0A806C77AC090336AB036671325939AA720863AE7F89194428B0751457893451") {
      //iniciar código;
}
```

Outra maneira, é você utilizar `Security.pageDomain`, este método retorna a String do domínio que o swf está hospedado.

```
if(Security.pageDomain == "http://www.seusiste.com.br/") {
    //iniciar código;
}
```

Para impedir que outros swfs consigam carregar o seu swf, você precisa utilizar justamente o código que você citou [Security.allowDomain()](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#allowDomain()). Passando como parâmetro o domínio que está apto para importar seu swf.

```
Security.allowDomain("http://www.seudominio.com.br/");
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava querendo muito obrigado !